# Finding value in a comma-separated text field in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, search, select

I've got a database of games with a genre field that has unique ids in it that are separated by commas. It's a text field. For example: `HALO 2 - cat_genre => '1,2' (Action,Sci-Fi)`

I'm trying to make a function that calculates the total number of games in that genre. So it's matching 1 value to multiple values separated by commas in the db.

I was using `SELECT * FROM gh_game WHERE cat_genre IN (1)` which would find Action Games.

I'm trying to work this out, I thought I had nailed it once before but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: the problem is the lack of db normalisation in the first place; there should be a genre table with one game id and cat id, one row per cat id

Comment: Instead of complicating the database scheme, you can often use `FIND_IN_SET()` - though that can become a performance drain.

Comment: I've used this approach before... but it only works as a one-way operation without destroying performance and maintainability.  Since you're trying to do a two-way lookup (looking into the table instead of just looking out), Dagon is right on the money... you need to separate this out into a new table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a many to many relation. like so

```
CREATE TABLE gameGenreTable ( id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, genreID, gameID)
```

EDIT: if you're using InnoDB you can also create foreign keys on genreID and gameID..
I would add a UNIQUE key on genreID, gameID

then you can do a query like this

```
SELECT genreID,count(genreID) as count from gameGenreTable GROUP BY genreID;
```

-- and join in your other table to get the genre name (or just use the ID).